# Android - create Utility class to play a sound

Tags: android, media-player

I have a sound that I want to be played when a button clicked. The same sound over many activities. So I thought it could be a good idea to create a Utility class that will have the method for playing the sound and I will call it from various activities, instead of creating a MediaPlayer variable in all the other activities. So I created this Utility class:

```
public class Utilities extends Activity {

public MediaPlayer mpPositive;
public MediaPlayer mpNegative;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mpPositive = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click_positive);
    mpNegative = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click_negative);
}


public void playPositive() {
    mpPositive.start();
}

}
```

In my activity I imported this file. And then I tried to use it like that:

```
public class ActivityListCategories extends ListActivity implements
     OnClickListener {
        private Utilities myUtilities;
        ...rest of the code...

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    myUtilities = new Utilities();
            ...rest of the code...
            }
    }

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnAdd:
        myUtilities.playPositive();
                    ...rest of the code...
}
```

But when I click the button - my app crashes. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please post the logcat.  How can we guess what error you are getting?

Comment: What's your reasoning for extending `Activity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code crashes because the `onCreate()` method of `Utilities` is never called as you don't use it as a normal `Activity`, and it doesn't follow the Activity life cycle. Due to this, your `this` reference will always be null.

Instead, try making it a normal Java class, something like:

```
public class Utilities extends Activity {

    public MediaPlayer mpPositive;
    public MediaPlayer mpNegative;

    public Utilities(Context context) {
        mpPositive = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.click_positive);
        mpNegative = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.click_negative);
    }


    public void playPositive() {
        mpPositive.start();
    }

}
```

And then create an object as follows:

```
Utilities utils = new Utilities(this);
```

Make sure this line is in `onCreate()` or after of your main Activity.

Comment: Thank you very much for such elaborated answer! I see where I got wrong, now it works perfectly!